# Dtsx designer files showing on *some* SSIS 2016 packages

Tags: visual-studio-2015, ssis, ssis-2016

In the following screenshot, you can see there are 7 SSIS packages with their corresponding `.dtsx` files. What I'm trying to understand is why 2 of the packages also show a `.dtsx.designer` file and if that's advantageous in anyway.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `.dtsx.designer` files are created for packages that contain 1 or more of the re-usable **Control Flow Package Parts**. This is a new feature in SSIS 2016.

The 2 packages you've highlighted likely have a control flow package part that has been re-used.

It's also a purely ***design-time only*** feature.

#### See: [MSDN - Reuse Control Flow across Packages by Using Control Flow Package Parts](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt620034.aspx)

[image]

**Further Reading:**

#### What's New in Integration Services 2016 - [Reusable control flow templates](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522534.aspx)

[image]

Comment: Beautiful. Yep, that's the difference. We've started implementing control flow templates. Thank you for saving my sanity.